# How do I print an ArrayList that contains an object with data in it?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

/*The following is the code to a Class containing two elements, name and boardFootage. I'll get the data from a Scanner, store it in an ArrayList in my Furniture object, then print out the items of the ArrayList in ascending order. 
*/

    class Furniture implements Comparable<Furniture> {
        public String toString() {
            return getName() + ": " + getBoardFootage() + "\n";
        }

        private String name;
        private double boardFootage;

        Furniture() {
            name = "";
            boardFootage = 0.0;
        }

        Furniture(String nameInput, double boardFootageInput) {
            name = nameInput;
            boardFootage = boardFootageInput;
        }


        public String getName() 
        {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            String name = "";
            while (!name.equalsIgnoreCase("quit"))
            {
                name = keyboard.next();
                if (name == "quit") {
                    System.out.println("Project Summary");
                    // PRINT LIST SORTED BY PROJECT SIZE FROM SMALLEST
                    // TO LARGEST USING Collections.sort METHOD
                }
            }
            return name;
        }


        public void setName(String name) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            this.name = keyboard.next();
        }


        public double getBoardFootage() {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            double boardFootage = 0.0;
            boardFootage = keyboard.nextDouble();
            return boardFootage;
        }


        public void setBoardFootage(double boardFottage) {
            Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
            this.boardFootage = keyboard.nextDouble();
        }

        public int compareTo(Furniture o) {
            if (this.boardFootage < o.boardFootage) {
                return -1;
            } else if (this.boardFootage > o.boardFootage) {
                return 1;
            }
            return this.name.compareTo(o.name);
        }
    }



    Furniture furniture = new Furniture();

    ArrayList<Furniture> furnitureList = new ArrayList<Furniture>();
```

Comment: Have you tried something yet?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, asking SO :P

Comment: [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/513832/1553851)

Comment: What's your real problem? Print the `List`? Tried `System.out.println()`?

Comment: Declaring a class within your main method is a.. strange practice.

Comment: What is your problem here? Print the List or sort it?

Comment: @DavidBittner I've been checking out Java decompilers recently, and one thing I found is that none of them can handle method local class. So, the one and only use for that might be to mess with decompilers. :)

Answer (score 1):

The way you would anytime?

```
//furnitureRef is a reference to a member of the list
for( Furniture furnitureRef : furnitureList ) {
    //Do stuff with furnitureRef
}
```

This seems like a homework question, so I'm cautious to give more help without you at least trying to do some yourself.

Additionally, the generally accepted way is to create a toString method for every object you define. This toString function should return a string of your object, serialized, such as:

```
class Car {
    String make;
    String model;

    public String toString() {
        return "{ make: " + make + " model: "+model+" }"; 
    }
}
```

This would then allow you to write:

```
//furnitureRef is a reference to a member of the list
for( Furniture furnitureRef : furnitureList ) {
    System.out.println( furnitureRef.toString() );
}
```

Comment: Don't name a variable `i` unless it's a simple index.

Comment: @shmosel eh, fair enough I suppose. Normally would, but I suppose if they really are a student it's good to set a proper example and not be lazy on examples :^)

Comment: You're apparently still "doing stuff with i" despite the fact there *is* no `i` :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo pfft, of course I'm not! Obviously you need to check the code again ;)

Comment: Your revisionism would be more effective if SO didn't have a history feature, and if you had also changed line 1 :-)

Comment: Honestly, it's comical at that point. A sick programmer is a bad programmer apparently.

Comment: That's better ...